# Formatting List of Figures: Spacing, Colon, Too Long Captions

Tags: tocloft

These issues have been discussed extensively on this forum, unfortunately i have failed to fix them. I have the following issues:

1. I would like to separate figure label and caption by a semicolon. Example: 
   Figure 1: This is the first figure.
2. Remove default spacing between two figure listing from different chapters. Example:

   Figure 1: This figure is from chapter 1

   Figure 2: This figure is also from chapter 1

   | %huge space

   | %that should be removed

   Figure 3: This figure is from chapter 2 and as a result, there is spacing 
   between Figure 2 and Figure 3 listings.
3. Align on the same margin two or more sentences resulting from figure 
   captions that are too long. Example:

   Figure 1: This is figure caption is so long that it extends to the second line and by so doing it is aligned on a different margin as the the start of the first line.

What should I do based of the following piece of code?

```
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{{\normalsize LIST OF FIGURES}}
\clearpage
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-2em}
\begin{center}
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\end{center}
```

Screenshot
[image: list of figures based on above code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring a full MWE, I'm going to assume that you're using a normal `report` class, and ignore the parts of the given preamble that don't have to do with the specific questions.

Feel free to adapt the below into a MWE for other questions:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
% Page references below from
% http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{0.7in} % from p. 9
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename{} } % from p. 9
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{: } % from p. 9
\begin{document}
\begingroup % from p. 12
\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}
\listoffigures
\endgroup
\chapter{One}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption for first figure in first chapter.
Caption for first figure in first chapter.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption for second figure in first chapter.
Caption for second figure in first chapter.}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Two}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption for first figure in second chapter.
Caption for first figure in second chapter.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption for second figure in second chapter.
Caption for second figure in second chapter.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mike Renfro. I get similar results, however, the separation between Figure label and Caption is not consistent. There is a gap initially, but at the end of the list there is no separation.

Comment: Double-digit values for either the chapter count, the figure count within a chapter, or both? If so, you'll need to make `\cftfignumwidth` large enough to accommodate your largest figure number values.